# Decimal to fraction conversion

Tags: algorithm

I got the following question for an interview:

Program to change a decimal to the nearest fraction.

Example:
0.12345 => 2649/20000

0.34 => 17/50

What is the best approach to solve this?

Comment: What makes this a programming question?

Comment: Which aspect of fractions don't you understand?

Comment: It's an algorithm question, which seems valid to me.  Still I would have liked to see a basic solution, with the question being "how can I optimize this."

Comment: See [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676481/optimized-algorithm-for-converting-a-decimal-to-a-pretty-fraction

Comment: @EricJ.: It may be valid, but it's not clear what the programming aspect is. It could be "How do I determine how many decimal places my floating point number has?", "How do I reduce a fraction?", or maybe "How do I compute the GCD of two numbers?".

Comment: you can find the answer for this question here:
http://www.getquiz.co/q/q_7256P70vr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decimal number is a fraction whose denominator is a power of ten (and similarly for any number base). So 0.34 is 34/100. Now just cancel the common factor, i.e. divide both numerator and denominator by their greatest common divisor.

You can find the GCD with a standard algorithm, which I leave to you to find.

Answer (score 6):

An approach I would come up with this late is get rid of the decimals:

0.12345 = 0.12345/1 = 12345/100000

Then find the [Greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) and divide both by it.

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds :-)  This solution only works for a terminating decimal value (e.g. not 1/3 = 0.3333..), which seems implied by the question but not conclusively stated.

Comment: @Eric, _all_ decimal values are terminating in IEEE754 :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: The OP used the term "decimal", never once referring to "floating point" or "IEEE 754".

Comment: Unless you're applying for a job as a mathematician rather than a programmer, that _will_ matter :-)

Answer (score 2):

http://homepage.smc.edu/kennedy_john/DEC2FRAC.PDF

In short:

> Let X be our decimal value. Z<sub>1</sub> == X, D<sub>0</sub> == 0 and D<sub>1</sub> == 1.
>
> Z<sub>i+1</sub> == 1 / (Z<sub>i</sub> - IntPart(Z<sub>i</sub>))
>
> D<sub>i+1</sub> == D<sub>i</sub> * IntPart(Z<sub>i+1</sub>) + D<sub>i-1</sub>
>
> N<sub>i+1</sub> == Round(X * D<sub>i+1</sub>)

When the algorithm has found, by iterating through these Z, D and N series from the fixed-point Z<sub>1</sub>, an index i of the series producing an N<sub>i</sub> and D<sub>i</sub> such that N<sub>i</sub> / D<sub>i</sub> == X, we're done. If there is a *de minimis* error (epsilon) within which a lower-terms approximation is acceptable, that error can be incorporated into the comparison of the working fraction with the input.

Prior to that condition being met, the series Z tracks the [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) of the decimal value, and the algorithm uses this factor to increase the denominator of the fraction until sufficient precision is attained.

Understand that the input value is best stored as a `decimal` type, and the calculation of N/D should also result in a decimal type, to avoid floating point rounding error.

The solution:

```
public struct Fraction
{
    public int Numerator { get; private set; }
    public int Denominator { get; private set; }

    public Fraction(int num, int denom) 
    {
        Numerator = num;
        Denominator = denom;
    }
    public decimal DecimalValue 
    { 
        get { return ((decimal)Numerator) / Denominator; } 
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Numerator.ToString() + "/" + Denominator.ToString();
    }

    public static Fraction FromDecimal(decimal x, decimal epsilon = 0.0000001m)
    {
        decimal z = x;
        decimal dPrev = 0;
        decimal dCur = 1;
        decimal dTemp = dCur;
        decimal n = 0;

        while ((Math.Abs(n / dCur) - x) > epsilon)
        {
            z = 1 / (z - (int)z);
            dTemp = dCur;
            dCur = (dCur * (int)z) + dPrev;
            dPrev = dTemp;
            n = Math.Round(x * dCur);
        }

        return new Fraction((int) n, (int) dCur);
    }
}
```

This algorithm is capable of finding the "true" fractional values of rational numbers that are artificially terminated due to precision limitations (i.e. .3333333 would be 1/3, not 3333333/10000000); it does this by evaluating each candidate fraction to produce a value that would be subject to the same precision limitations as the input. It actually depends upon that; feeding this algorithm the true value of *pi* (if you could) would cause an infinite loop. However, this behavior creates a weakness in the algorithm when expecting arbitrarily-low epsilons (including zero); representations of irrational numbers, or of decimal values not exactly equal to the value produced by the division inherent in the fraction, can produce unexpected results.

Comment: +1 Simple and efficient. I just changed the while condition to allow for approximate solutions with controled error: `while (abs(n / dCur - x) > 1E-6)`

Answer (score 1):

Naive solution..

1. 0.12345 = 12345 / 100000
2. find greatest common divisor
3. divide both of the parts of fraction with the GCD
4. profit

Answer (score 1):

First, make the numerator and denominator integral by multiplying continuously by ten.

So, 0.34/1 becomes 34/100, and 0.12345/1 becomes 12345/100000

Then use a GCD calculation to get the greatest common divisor of those two numbers, and divide them both by that.

The GCD of 34 and 100 is 2, which gives you 17/50. The GCD of 12345 and 1000000 is 5, which gives you 2469/20000.

A recursive GCD function in C is:

```
int gcd (int a, int b) {
    return (b == 0) ? a : gcd (b, a%b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Kerrek SB is correct, but using **continued fractions** it is easy to find the **best rational approximation** of any real number (represented as a float or not), *for any given maximal denominator*. 
The optimal property of the method is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Some_useful_theorems, theorem 4 and 5.

Example results: approximate sqrt(2) with a denominator less or equal to 23:

```
findapprox(math.sqrt(2),23)
          (3, 2)  new error frac: 6.0660e-02 
          (7, 5)  new error frac: 1.0051e-02 
        (17, 12)  new error frac: 1.7346e-03 
        (41, 29)  new error frac: 2.9731e-04 
result: (17, 12)
```

Example: approximate 23.1234 with denominator <=20000:

```
findapprox(23.1234,20000)
            (185, 8)  new error frac: 6.9194e-05 
          (1688, 73)  new error frac: 4.8578e-06 
          (1873, 81)  new error frac: 2.4560e-06 
         (3561, 154)  new error frac: 1.0110e-06 
         (5434, 235)  new error frac: 1.8403e-07 
        (19863, 859)  new error frac: 3.0207e-08 
       (25297, 1094)  new error frac: 1.5812e-08 
       (45160, 1953)  new error frac: 4.4287e-09 
       (70457, 3047)  new error frac: 2.8386e-09 
      (115617, 5000)  new error frac: 0.0000e+00 
result: (115617, 5000) (exact)
```

Continued fractions have some funky characteristics. For example sqrt(2) can be written as 1,2,2,,...  meaning 1+1/(2+1/(2+1/...). So we can find optimal rational approximations for sqrt(2):

```
rewrap([1]+[2]*30) gives 367296043199 / 259717522849, 
all correct: 1.4142135623730951
```

Here's the code (python).

```
# make a+1/(b+1/(c+1/...)) cont fraction of a float
# no special care taken to accumulation of float truncation errors.
def contfrac(v):
    nums=None
    while nums==None or len(nums)<20:
        if not nums:
            nums=[]
        vi=int(v)
        v=v-vi
        nums.append(vi)
        if v<=0 : 
            return nums
        v=1.0/v
    return nums


# make tuple representing a rational number based on a cont f list 
# this is exact
def rewrap(v):
    rat=(0,1)
    first=1
    for k in reversed(v):
        if first:
            first=0
            rat=(k,1)
        else:            
            rat=(k*rat[0]+rat[1],rat[0])        
    return rat

# float evaluate a ratio
def makefloat(v):
    return v[0]*1.0/v[1]

# find the best rational approximation with denominator <=maxdenom
def findapprox(flt,maxdenom):
    flt=1.0*flt
    cf=contfrac(flt)
    best=(cf[0],1)
    errfrac=1e9
    for i in range(2,len(cf)):
        new=rewrap(cf[:i])        
        newerrfrac=abs((flt-makefloat(new))/flt)
        print "%20s"%(str(new)),
        print(" new error frac: %5.4e " %(newerrfrac))
        if new[1]>maxdenom or newerrfrac>errfrac:
            return best
        best=new
        errfrac=newerrfrac
        if newerrfrac ==0: 
            return best
    return best
```

Answer (score 0):

1. get rid of dot :  (0.a<sub>1</sub>..a<sub>n</sub> * 10<sup>n</sup>) / (1*10<sup>n</sup>)
2. x = [GCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)( a<sub>1</sub>..a<sub>n</sub> , 10<sup>n</sup>)
3. (a<sub>1</sub>..a<sub>n</sub>/x) / (10<sup>n</sup>/x)

```cs
foo(double a) {
    int digits = (int)log(a, 10);
    int x = GCD((int)(a * 10^digits) , 10^digits);
    return ((int)(a * 10^digits) / x) + " / " + (10^digits / x);    
}
```

Comment: Note that in c# `^` is the bitwise XOR operator, not the power function. Just in case you are using c#.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks, it is actually pseudo code. but thanks for clarifying for avoiding confusion

Answer (score 0):

First, convert your numbers to an obvious fraction

```
0.34 => 34/100
```

and

```
0.12345 => 12345/100000
```

Now reduce the fractions. You will need to find the GCD of the numerator and the denominator. The GDC of 34 and 100 is 2. Divide both numbers by 2 and you get 17/50.

See [Greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) on Wikipedia. You will also find a brief description of an algorithm for GCD there.