# Formatting Numbers in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a formatter

```
let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 8
            return formatter
        }()
```

I want to let formatter to receive fractions like 1/3, 1/10, 5/115 and convert it into decimal number. Is it possible to fix?

I am expecting to get from 2/3 0.66666667 etc.

Comment: Please update your question showing what you have tried. Certainly if you pass `1.0/3.0` into the formatter you will get the correct result.

Comment: if i pass 1.0/3.0 in my formatter, i am getting a result "1". Cause this formatter can only read the first part of this number.

Comment: @РостиславЛяпкин Please, show as a minimal, reproducible example how you are using the formatter.

Comment: TextField("\(matrixA[row-1][column-1])", value: $matrixA[row-1][column-1], formatter: formatter).multilineTextAlignment(.center). Thats an example of using this formatter. User is typing something in TextField.

Comment: For example it can be like TextField("\\(a)", value: a, formatter: formatter). a is a Double

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit your question and add the additional code there (The lack of carriage returns and white space makes anything more than a few characters unreadable in the comments section. Plus future readers shouldn't have to wade through the question and a bunch of comments to understand the question.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61114799/2303865

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `NumberFormatters` are able to parse mathematical expressions like the string "1.0/3.0".

So I believe the answer to your question is no.

If you do a google search on "swift arithmetic expression parser" it looks like there are few open source frameworks that might do what you want.

Comment: That's a bit sad, but thank you for you answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61114799/2303865

Comment: That thread shows a `RationalFormatter` that will convert Double values to fractions. The OP needs the opposite: Converting fraction strings to Doubles (which should be easier.) I assume there is a reverse function defined in the Formatter class? (Something like `value(for:String)`.) I’m on an iPad at the moment and don’t have access to the Xcode help system.